# Python3: Send email message containing binary data?

Tags: email, python-3.x, smtp, message, mime

The [following](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string) fails:

```
>>> a = email.message.Message()
>>> a.set_payload(b'some data')
>>> a.as_string()
TypeError: string payload expected: <class 'bytes'>
```

It also fails using a generator explicitly, and calling [`flatten`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator.flatten). The message body is converted to ASCII, escapes applied and then finally converted to bytes for transmission anyway, so why can I not set a bytes payload?

How do I go about getting a preferably non-MIME message with a bytes payload that [`smtplib.SMTP.send_message`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message) will accept?

Comment: You'll probably have to encode it to a string.  I don't know what's available in Python but usually it would be in Base-64.

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, if you can do it, non-ASCII, non-MIME-typed mail is going to be trouble on the receiving side and probably on any intermediate Mail Transfer Agents. Where "trouble" means "hard to interpret" or "bounced" or "discarded".

Comment: @msw - Death to the mail agents who are still ASCII only! :)

Comment: @msw: On the contrary, the Message is converted to ASCII first regardless on the sender end. I just don't see the point of picking a random string encoding for my bytes, just to have then encoded as ASCII later anyway (and then back to bytes of course -.-).

Comment: Why don't you two-byte pad it and convert it to Unicode (or pick your favorite esoteric encoding)?  Then on the other end you could convert from a Unicode string to bytes.  I would still recommend the MIME solution, if only because the libraries are there to help you out and it is the standard, but converting to a string might work.

Answer (score 1):

Remember:  in Python 3 strings are **all** unicode.  You are effectively giving Python a bytes object and then telling it you want a unicode string, but not telling it which encoding to use to convert the bytes object to a string.

What you need to do is provide the encoding as the second parameter to the `set_payload()` call, like so:

```
test = email.message.Message()
test.set_payload(b'some example_data', 'latin1') # use latin-1 for no-op translation
test.as_string()

'MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="latin1"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\nc29tZSBleGFtcGxlIGRhdGE=\n'
```

This does give a MIME type message -- hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: Can you explain your choice of latin1?

Comment: latin1 and unicode are the same for the first 256 characters, so the bytes won't be changed during the 'decode' process.